# ¿Cómo obtengo el valor de un Checkbox cuando no ha sido elegido?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, jsp

Resulta que debo obtener el valor de un checkbox que no ha sido seleccionado, actualmente el código que he construido falla en el momento que doy el primer envío de mis datos, regreso a la pagina y realizo el mismo intento y al parecer funciona, pero si intento por tecera vez comienza a mandarme valores nulos

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>Contenido de PRUEBA</div>
        <form action="test.jsp" method="get">
        <input type="hidden" id ="status_1_h" name="status_1" value="0" />
        <input type="checkbox" id="status_1" name="status_1" value="CHECK" /> Check 1 <br />
        <input type="hidden" id="status_2_h" name="status_2" value="0" /> 
        <input type="checkbox" id="status_2" name="status_2" value="CHECK" /> Check 2 <br />
        <input type="hidden" id = "status_3_h" name="status_3" value="0" />
        <input type="checkbox" id="status_3" name="status_3" value="CHECK" /> Check 3 <br />
        <input type="submit" name="btnsend" value="Send">
        </form>
    <Script>
        if(document.getElementById("status_1").checked) {
            document.getElementById('status_1_h').disabled = true;
        }
        if(document.getElementById("status_2").checked) {
            document.getElementById('status_2_h').disabled = true;
        }
        if(document.getElementById("status_3").checked) {
            document.getElementById('status_3_h').disabled = true;
        }
    </Script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Actualmente estoy enviando los datos a un jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>

        <%
           String status_1 = request.getParameter("status_1");
           String status_2 = request.getParameter ("status_2");
           String status_3 = request.getParameter("status_3");

           out.print("<br>"+status_1
                   + "<br>"+status_2
                   + "<br>"+status_3);
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Podrían realizar la prueba y decirme que pasa por que no entiendo :o

Ya le he probado en tres navegadores distintos y sigue igual.

Muchas gracias :d

Comment: para que necesitas eso?

Comment: @Luis Lo necesito por que en el proyecto que deseo realizar no puedo enviar valores nulos a mi bases de datos... Por lo que debo enviar un espacio en blanco asi : value=" " en caso de que la persona no haga check en una opcion

Comment: si tu sabes cuantos checkbox tienes, y sabiendo que solo se puede selccionar un checkbox a la vez, por que no haces esas validaciones en el lado del servidor. me refiero a que solo del checkbox que obtengas es el que llevará la info y los demás automáticamente son vacíos no?

Comment: Puedes explicar un poco mejor lo que quieres hacer? no entiendo nada. Aun así creo que podría ayudarte utilizar lo siguiente para dejar alguno de los valores marcados por defecto: `<input type="radio" name="test-name" checked>` O esto para poner el campo como obligatorio: `<input type="text" required>`

Comment: El problema es que en el servidor no puedes capturar por POST los valores de los checkbox  no seleccionados **porque estos no se envían** al servidor. Tendrías entonces que recoger su estado y enviarlos. [En esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/198051/29967) hay un ejemplo de cómo recorrer cada checkbox, se guarda su id y su estado (true/false)  si está chequeado o no. Puedes agregar esa información a los datos que van a ser enviados al servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Es como cuando tú envías un ***POST*** de un formulario. Si no le pones nada, al llegar al servidor lo toma como ***null***. Lo primero que yo plantearía es si esos ***Checkbox*** van a ser todos requeridos, pero como yo no sé eso, sino tú lo sabes... Te daré las dos posibles respuesta para ambos casos:

No sé ***JSP***, pero sí ***PHP***. Supongo que es casi la misma sintaxis:

> Éste es el `index` de mi ejemplo:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="check.php" method="POST">

            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="value1">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" value="value1">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" value="value3">

        <input type="submit" name="">

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

> El archivo `check.php`

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['checkbox1'])) {
        echo $_POST['checkbox1']; // Imprimes o haces tu lógica ;)
    }

    if(isset($_POST['checkbox2'])) {
        echo $_POST['checkbox2'];
    }

    if(isset($_POST['checkbox3'])) {
        echo $_POST['checkbox3'];
    }
```

La función ***`isset()`*** en este caso comprueba que la variable puesta en su parámetro esté definida y no sea ***`NULL`***.
Recuerda que los formularios es más seguro enviarlos con el método ***`POST`***.

Comment: -.-' aiii seria un gusto saber de php... pero no lo manejo jaja... Soy demasiado novato, y por ahora solo estoy haciendo un proyecto pequeño como practica en jsp... podrías ayudarme con el codigo en javascript? ese medio lo conozco :D

Comment: en tu archivo jsp pon estás validaciones:  `if(request.getParameter("status_1") !=  null){
 
String status_1= request.getParameter ("status_1");
 // haces tu lógica, porque el dato si llego
}else{
//Aqui no se enviaron los datos.. lanza un mensaje :/
}`

Comment: Pos si eso lo había pensado también... pero quedo triste por que queria hacerlo de la forma anterior... de igual manera tu aporte fue de mucha ayuda :D Gracias:d no sabia que podía hacer esa validación de esa manera, gracias:D

Answer (score 0):

El Posible Problema esta en que las etiquetas script están mal escritas y que también tienes argumentos con comillas que expresan función en vez de texto...

Prueba con esto en la parte del Script...

```js
<html>
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
    <div>Contenido de PRUEBA</div>
    <form action="test.jsp" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" id ="status_1_h" name="status_1" value="0" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="status_1" name="status_1" value="CHECK" /> Check 1 <br />
    <input type="hidden" id="status_2_h" name="status_2" value="0" /> 
    <input type="checkbox" id="status_2" name="status_2" value="CHECK" /> Check 2 <br />
    <input type="hidden" id = "status_3_h" name="status_3" value="0" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="status_3" name="status_3" value="CHECK" /> Check 3 <br />
    <input type="submit" name="btnsend" value="Send">
    </form>
<script>
    if(document.getElementById("status_1").checked) {
        document.getElementById("status_1_h").disabled = true;
    }
    if(document.getElementById("status_2").checked) {
        document.getElementById("status_2_h").disabled = true;
    }
    if(document.getElementById("status_3").checked) {
        document.getElementById("status_3_h").disabled = true;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>

    <%
       String status_1 = request.getParameter("status_1");
       String status_2 = request.getParameter ("status_2");
       String status_3 = request.getParameter("status_3");

       out.print("<br>"+status_1 + "<br>" + status_2 + "<br>" + status_3);
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: document.getElementById('status_1_h').disabled = document.getElementById("status_1").checked;

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero es entender como funcionan los inputs de tipo checkbox en HTML, si dentro de un formulario HTML5 tienes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="2">
```

*Si NO usas javascript* y envías el formulario sin marcar los checkboxes, ninguno de esos checkboxes (o sus valores) se envía con el formulario.
Un checkbox debe estar marcado para que se envía con el formulario que lo contiene.
Por tanto la forma de saber que un checkbox NO se marcó es NO recibirlo en el servidor.

Ahora, cada checkbox (o input en general, debe tener un `label` asociado, bien envolviéndolo, o usando la ID, p.e.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="1" id="option1">
<label for="option1">Opción 1</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="2" id="option2">
<label for="option2">Opción 2</label>
```

Esto no influye en nada a la hora de enviar los campos, es una cuestión de uso correcto y accesibilidad. Ahora, los nombres de los checkboxes son incorrectos, ya que en este caso no están relacionanos, cuando aparentemente se require que si lo esten (marcando una serie de opciones de un grupo). Entonces deben nombrarse con el mismo nombre, pero si se usa, p.e. "options", sólo se recibirá el valor del último checkbox seleccionado, el estado de los precedentes sería desconocido. Los checkboxes asociados se nombran entonces con sintaxis de array, p.e. "options[]", de esta forma al servidor llegará un array de los valores de los checkboxes seleccionados del formulario. Ejemplo:

Opción 1


    
    Opción 2

Como anteriormente, del contenido de ese array puedes inferir que checkboxes no fueron seleccionados.

Ahora, *Si usas javascript* pueden hacer muchas cosas, p.e. si quieres recibir un array con los valores de todos los checkboxes de un grupo, junto al array de los valores marcados, y luego obtener los que no lo están, puedes leer todos los checkboxes en el momento de enviar el formulario (deteniendo el evento), guardar los valores de todos los checkboxes (o de los no seleccionados si así lo quieres) en un *input de tipo oculto* y enviar el formulario, mediante JS.