# Como guardar checkbox seleccionados y no seleccionados

Tags: php, mysql

Los pongo un poco en contexto, estoy haciendo un sistema de registro de asistencia académico, y tengo pensado guardar en una tabla la id de los estudiantes junto con un valor que me diga si asistieron o no a clases para que luego de esto se saque un porcentaje de las inasistencias de cada estudiante.

[image: Tabla de ejemplo]

Arriba tienen la tabla de como quedaria aproximadamente, mi idea es que a los asistentes se les marque con un check y los inasistentes se dejen vacíos y eso se envie. Genial una vez dicho esto vamos al codigo...

```
<?php foreach($resultado as $dato): ?>
   <tr>
      <td><?php echo $dato["nombre"] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dato["cedula"] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dato["acreditable"] ?></td>
  <form action="asistencia_dia.php" method="POST">
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="asistencia[]"></td>
      <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $dato["id"] ?>" name="estudiante[<?php $dato["id"] ?>]">
   </tr>
<?php endforeach ?>    
  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Explico un poco mi desastre: **$resultado** no es mas que una variable la cual almacena una sentecia sql, ese se supone seria mi formulario para mandar 2 datos y poder guardarlos que son el id de cada uno de los estudiantes que se almacenan en el input oculto y los checkbox.

Y los recibia de esta manera:

```
if($_POST){
$estudiante = $_POST["estudiante"];

    echo "<ul>";
    foreach( $_POST["asistencia"] as $asistencia=> $item1)
    {
        echo "<li>";
        echo $item1; 
        echo "</li>"; 
        echo $estudiante[$asistencia];
    }
     echo "</ul>";
}
```

Eso que ven es solo una prueba, quería visualizar que según el check que marque sea la id correspondiente, aun no llego a la parte de guardarlo en la base de datos.

Una vez dicho todo eso **Mi problema** es que si bien capturo cuando el checkbox se marca y lo veo, no detecto cual es el que presione, osea si por ejemplo marco el checkbox 3 me deberia decir: on 3, pero contrario a eso me dice: on 1..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y mi meta es que me diga si marco solo el checkbox 1 me diga: On 1, osea que presione fue el check uno y asi con todos, si presione el primer check y el tercero entonces me diga: On 1 y On 3..

Por ejemplo:
Si=1
No=0

Alumno Asistencia
José si
Pedro no
María si

Me debería enviar así
si
no
si

Pero me envía así:
si
si
no

Eso seria mi problema, gracias de antemano a cualquiera que me pueda ayudar, y si tiene algo de tiempo de ayudarme con lo demas que explicaba, es decir guardar  en una base de datos quien de los estudiantes tuvieron check(osea asistieron) y cuando no y luego hacer la especie de "conteo" para saber cuantas inasistencias o el porcentaje de inasistencias que tendría se lo agradecería muchísimo. Espero poder haberme explicado mi problema bien.

Comment: No es conveniente enviar información al servidor cada vez que un elemento es chequeado o no, sería una mala práctica desde el punto de vista del rendimiento. Debes delegar todo a tu botón `Enviar`.  Al hacer clic en él puedes enviar un array al servidor con dos valores: **el id del estudiante y el estado del checkbox**. Lo interesante es que, en la misma propiedad `value` del checkbox puedes poner el id del estudiante. [Mira esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/100952/29967), si observas el segundo console.log verás que da un array justamente con la información que requieres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leyendo de manera global el planteamiento del problema, me parece que estás enfocando mal la solución: te estás preocupando demasiado por lo que el código hace cada vez que se presiona alguno de los checkboxes.

Si lo piensas bien, según he entendido, no tiene ninguna importancia controlar lo que ocurre cada vez que alguien marca o desmarca el checkbox.

La forma habitual de proceder en estos casos es recoger el estado del formulario al presionar en el botón enviar, mediante un recorrido de todos los checkboxes.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo.

En él agrupamos todos los checkboxes por la misma etiqueta  `name` (esto es útil cuando tenemos en un formulario solamente un cierto grupo de elementos que queremos alcanzar... se pueden agrupar también por clases).

Además, usamos la etiqueta `value` del checkbox para almacenar el id del estudiante.

Verás que el código construye un objeto organizado donde cada par de elementos son el id del estudiante y el estatus del checkbox, **justo la información que necesitas para trabajar en el servidor**.

Luego mandas ese objeto al servidor, lo desmenuzas y lo usas para hacer la inserción o para lo que haga falta.

Este es el código:

```js
$("#btnEnviar").click(function() {
  var arrTodo = new Array();
  /*Agrupamos todos los input con name=cbxEstudiante*/
  $('input[name="cbxEstudiante"]').each(function(element) {
    var item = {};
    item.id = this.value;
    item.status = this.checked;
    arrTodo.push(item);
  });

  /*Creamos un objeto para enviarlo al servidor*/
  var toPost = JSON.stringify(arrTodo);
  console.log(toPost);
  
  /*
    Aquí convendría lanzar una petición Ajax al servidor
    enviándole la variabel toPost
    En el servidor desglosamos esa variable
    obteniendo cada id y cada estatus y procesamos los datos
  */

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table is-striped">
  <theader>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Estatus</th>
  </theader>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Pedro</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cbxEstudiante" value="1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Santiago</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cbxEstudiante" value="2" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>María</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cbxEstudiante" value="3" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Juan</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cbxEstudiante" value="4" /></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <a class="button is-primary" id="btnEnviar">Enviar</a>
```

Al servidor estarás enviando un objeto ordenado, que podrás convertir en array para trabajar de una forma igualmente ordenada y transparente:

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "status": true
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "status": false
}, {
    "id": "3",
    "status": true
}, {
    "id": "4",
    "status": false
}]
```

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar colocando tu codigo de esta forma:

```
<form action="asistencia_dia.php" method="POST">
  <?php foreach($resultado as $dato): ?>
     <tr>
        <td><?php echo $dato["nombre"] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $dato["cedula"] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $dato["acreditable"] ?></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="asistencia[]"></td>
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $dato["id"] ?>" name="estudiante[<?php $dato["id"] ?>]">
     </tr>
  <?php endforeach ?>    
  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Básicamente lo que hacemos es colocar la etiqueta `form` de apertura antes del `foreach`.

Saludos!

Comment: No hace ninguna diferencia el resultado sigue siendo el mismo, pero gracias por tu aporte amigo

Comment: hay una clara diferencia, y es que solo hay un unico formulario en lugar de uno por cada registro que tengas. Por otra parte, hay un error: falta un `echo` en el campo hidden, en el nombre. Deberia ser: `<?php echo $dato["id"] ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Yo te sugiero que plantees tu formulario, de manera que cada vez que CAMBIE el estado de un CHECKBOX haga un submit con los datos a actualizar (ID del Estudiante y Asistencia SI/NO).

Quedaría algo así:

```
<?php foreach($resultado as $dato): ?>
   <tr>
      <td><?php echo $dato["nombre"] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dato["cedula"] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $dato["acreditable"] ?></td>

      <td>
        <form action="asistencia_dia.php" method="POST">
          <input type="checkbox" name="asistencia<?php echo $dato["id"]; ?>" onchange="submit()">
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $dato["id"]; ?>" name="estudiante<?php echo $dato["id"]; ?>">
        </form>
      </td>
   </tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Recuerda que un input de tipo checkbox al ser enviado en un submit solo llega si esta marcado. Si no esta marcado no llega al destino definido en action.

Answer (score 0):

La opción que te dan de hacer submit por cada check es buena, hasta cierto punto, pues serán muchas peticiones dependiendo de la cantidad de alumnos.

Te dejo otra opción que podría funcionar:

**Primero:**

```
<form action="asistencia_dia.php" method="POST">
   <?php foreach($resultado as $dato): ?>
       <tr>
          <td><?php echo $dato["nombre"] ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $dato["cedula"] ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $dato["acreditable"] ?></td>
          <td>
              // Aquí concatenamos el id del alumno al nombre del check
              // para poder identificarlo sin problema cuando se envie
              <input type="checkbox" name="asistencia-<?= $dato["id"]; ?>">
              <input type="hidden" value="<?= $dato["id"]; ?>" name="estudiantes[]">
         </td>
       </tr>
   <?php endforeach ?>    
   <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

**Luego:**
Del lado del servidor hacemos lo siguiente para procesar las asistencias.

```
if($_POST){
    // Se obtiene el array(lista) de alumnos
    $estudiantes = (array)$_POST["estudiantes"];

    echo "<ul>";
    foreach( $estudiantes as $estudiante){
       echo "<li>";
       echo 'Alumno: ' . $estudiante;
       // Comprobamos si el alumno tiene asistencia o no
       // Recuerda concatenar la palabra asistencia-, con el id del alumno
       // para hacer referencia al check correcto
       $asistencia = $_POST["asistencia-" . $estudiante] == 'on' ? "Si" : "No";
       echo " Asistió:" . $asistencia;
       echo "</li>"; 
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Y eso sería todo.

NOTA: el ejemplo anterior no lo pude testear, pero puedes probar para verificar si te funciona, y si marca algún error o duda solo deja saberlo.

Answer (score 0):

Te planteo la solucion parecida a la de Jesus Magallon.

```
<?php 
$resultado = [
    ['id'=>1,'nombre'=>'Fabio',   'cedula'=>'c1','acreditable'=>''],
    ['id'=>2,'nombre'=>'Ernesto', 'cedula'=>'c2','acreditable'=>''],
    ['id'=>5,'nombre'=>'Marcos',  'cedula'=>'c5','acreditable'=>''],
    ['id'=>9,'nombre'=>'Saul',    'cedula'=>'c9','acreditable'=>''],
    ['id'=>7,'nombre'=>'Jeronimo','cedula'=>'c7','acreditable'=>''],
    ['id'=>3,'nombre'=>'Raul',    'cedula'=>'c3','acreditable'=>''],
];
?>

<form action="asistencia_dia.php" method="POST">'

<?php foreach($resultado as $dato): ?>
     <tr>
        <td><?php echo $dato["nombre"] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $dato["cedula"] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $dato["acreditable"] ?></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="asistencia[]" value="<?php echo $dato["id"] ?>"></td>
     </tr>
  <?php endforeach ?>    
  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Realmente no te haría falta el input hidden, puesto que el propio checkbox lleva un valor, el del id del estudiante.

En el archivo `asistencia_dia.php`, te va a llegar en el $_POST un array con indice `asistencia`, y con valores los ids de aquellos que están marcados. Con lo cual sabes QUIENES han asistido. Ya en tu bbdd actualizas esos ids con asistencia=true o como sea en tu modelo de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias por tomarse el tiempo y aportarme variadas respuestas, al final se me ocurrió el simple hecho de que en vez de guardar si el checkbox estaba vació o no (**OJO ESTO SE GUARDA ÚNICAMENTE AL PRESIONARSE EL BOTÓN ENVIAR, SOLO QUE EN MUCHAS FOTOS SIN QUERER LO CORTE**), Solo cree una evento en Javascript que cambiara el valor de un input hidden cada que este se presionara su respectivo checkbox

Es decir: Va a existir un input hidden por defecto con el valor de 1 y cada que el checkbox correspondiente se presione entonces cambio el valor a 2, así determino con el numero 1 que el estudiante no asistió y con el numero 2 que el estudiante si asistió a clases. Y de esta manera lo guardo en la base de datos.

No se si sera la mejor solución o si me traerá problemas mas adelante, pero por ahora funciona, muchas gracias nuevamente a todos por sus respuestas.